# Как лучше всего узнать об изменении размера элемента со скролом?

Tags: javascript

Есть старый способ по `setInterval` отслеживать изменение размеров, можно отслеживать с помощью `MutationObserver` добавление изменение элементов. Но вчера, чисто случайно, я наткнулся на какую-то статью, в которой рассказывали, как круто отслеживать изменение в бесконечном скролле,с помощью чего-то, что я не перечислил. Чтобы это могло быть? Какие ещё есть способы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно там говорилось о [IntersectionObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserver)

> Intersection Observer API позволяет веб-приложениям асинхронно следить за изменением пересечения элемента с его родителем или областью видимости документа viewport.

Но это экспериментальная технология - [Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserver#Browser_compatibility)